# How to load zip of html directory into iframe (JS)?

Tags: javascript, iframe, jszip

I have a zip file containing an HTML file and an image:

```
.
├── index.html
├── img/
    └── test.png
```

The html includes the image using a relative url: `<img src="img/test.png">` If one was to load this html file in the browser, the image would appear. Similarly, other linked assets would also load, such as styles and scripts with relative URLS (if there were any).

What I am trying to do is load index.html (with the relative assets) into an iframe using jszip.

This is what I have so far:

```
<iframe id="output"></iframe>
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById("output");
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('/test.zip', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }

        JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
            var index = zip.files['index.html'].async("string")
                .then(function(data){
                    // Load data (string with page HTML) into iframe
                    var iframeWindow = iframe;
                    if(iframeWindow.contentWindow) {
                        iframeWindow = iframeWindow.contentWindow;
                    } else {
                        if(iframeWindow.contentDocument.document) {
                            iframeWindow = iframeWindow.contentDocument.document;
                        } else {
                            iframeWIndow = iframeWindow.contentDocument;
                        }
                    }
                    iframeWindow.document.open();
                    iframeWindow.document.write(data);
                    iframeWindow.document.close();
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The script correctly loads the HTML file into the iframe, but, as expected, the image is broken.

The only method I can think of to solve this is to replace every relative url with a [data url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). However, I don't know how to go about doing this. (Nor do I know for sure whether it would work.) Any sugguestions?

Comment: Hi @PullJosh, did you get any workaround/solution for this?

Comment: @vindev This was a long time ago, but I don't think so. If I were to try again today I would probably look at either replacing all URLs in the HTML with Blob URLs (see this post I wrote: https://dev.to/pulljosh/how-to-load-html-css-and-js-code-into-an-iframe-2blc) or hijacking a service worker to intercept all page loads. No idea if that could actually work but it's worth a shot.